# React routing not working while deploying build on production

Tags: reactjs

I am using React version 18.2.0 and react-dom 6.4.0. I am able to redirect on local, there component can be easily switch from one to another. However, after deploying to production its URL gets changed but component doesn't load.

How can I resolve the issue?

```
const Project = lazy(() => import("./pages/Project/Project"));
<Route exact path="/" element={<Project />}></Route>
```

package.json

```
 "react": "^18.2.0",
"react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.1",
"react-dnd": "^16.0.1",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.15.0",
"react-hook-form": "^7.36.1",
"react-organizational-chart": "^2.2.0",
"react-quill": "^2.0.0",
"react-quilljs": "^1.3.3",
"react-redux": "^8.0.4",
"react-router-dom": "^6.0.0",
"react-scripts": "^5.0.1"
```

Comment: Do you use a basepath in production? Is there anything else breaking in the console? Is logging set up to show you if there was a crash?

Comment: What platform are you deploying it on?

Comment: @LelandB No error found on Console.js and even i tried to run npm run build and then serve - s build it still gives no routing only url change

Comment: @technophyle I am deploying on Microsoft azure, It was working fine one day before and we haven't deploy any code on production related with that

Comment: I don' think there is enough info here, and a lot could be going on. Are there config changes between local and prod in .env files? Maybe the url is malformed?

Comment: i am also facing the issue. only url changing, not the view. but only in production. locally, its working just fine.

Comment: @LelandB, let me update the more package version so that we can compare

Comment: @ArifSajal any luck till now?

Comment: what does this question have to do with [tag:angular]?

Comment: Its mentioned above in react js

Comment: i am still trying to find solution.

Comment: everything working well in local environment. problem starts, when build and deployed in nginx container with kubernetes. tried to build locally. but no luck.

Comment: See the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) to see if there's a relevant section pertaining to where/how you are deploying the app. The basic gist is that the hosting service/server needs to be setup/configured to serve/return the root index.html file for all page requests into the app.

Comment: It is resolved , I have made some changes on react-router-dom package version, I have set to 6.0.0 version